# ASP.NET MVC3 - application start folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've got a problem finding application start folder in MVC3 on server.
I've got some files on server and I neet to get to them while rendering View

Right now my core looks like this

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\EndlessPathtoMyApp\Layouts\");
```

But I need it to be more dynamic so it will work no metter where app folder is

Any help (I'm using razor MVC3 if it helps)?

EOG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Server.MapPath("~/Layouts");`

The ~ is the root of your application. This works across all ASP.NET and MVC versions.